# BABEL parse error: transpiling react js into js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, transpiler

I'm trying to transpile my react jsx code into js using babel. This is the command I used:

```
npx babel BlueSlide/js/student_slider.jsx --watch --out-file BlueSlide/static/js/student_slider_compiled.js
```

When I do this I get this error

```
  49 |   render() {
  50 |     return (
> 51 |       <div class="jumbotron thinking">
     |       ^
  52 |         <h1>Welcome To Blue Slide</h1>
  53 |         <p>How well do you understand what's going on</p>
  54 |         <div class="slidecontainer">
    at Parser.raise (/Users/joshua/Websites/BlueSlide/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6344:17)
    at Parser.unexpected (/Users/joshua/Websites/BlueSlide/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7659:16)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/joshua/Websites/BlueSlide/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8828:20)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/joshua/Websites/BlueSlide/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8413:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/joshua/Websites/BlueSlide/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8393:21)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/Users/joshua/Websites/BlueSlide/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8280:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/joshua/Websites/BlueSlide/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8253:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/joshua/Websites/BlueSlide/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8200:21)
    at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/Users/joshua/Websites/BlueSlide/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8963:28)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/joshua/Websites/BlueSlide/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8760:21) {
  pos: 1356,
  loc: Position { line: 51, column: 6 },
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR'
}
```

I tried replacing the inside of the render function with just a simple div and the same problem. I don't know why it's yelling at me for my render return statement.

I just want the react code to be compiled so that I can use it with my HTML and if this isn't the right way to do it, feel free to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

first install babel-cli

```
npm i babel-cli -g //install globally so u can use anywhere
```

Babel is a compiler but it is not going to compile anything by default. We have to add plugins and pre-sets in order to get any sort of change in our code. you have to install

```
 npm i babel-preset-env babel-preset-react --save-dev
```

now you need to create two directories. public and src. in public folder place index.js and index.html.

index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="here"></div>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="./index.js"></script> //index.js
```

index.js should be empty. we will write our jsx code in src directory, babel will transpile it onto index.js

now in src folder create app.js and run this code for testing

src/app.js

```
const template = <p>this is jsx</p>;
const appRoot = document.getElementById("here");
ReactDOM.render(template2, appRoot);
```

now in command line run this code:

```
babel src/app.js --out-file=public/index.js --presets=env,react --watch
```

if you check the public/index.js

```
"use strict";

var template = React.createElement(
  "p",
  null,
  "this is jsx"
);
var appRoot = document.getElementById("here");
ReactDOM.render(template2, appRoot);
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your babel.rc file, but I suspect you haven't installed `@babel/preset-react` and added it to your config. This is needed to transpile the JSX syntax.

Comment: yup. I don't really know what those. So I need to make a babel.rc in the root of the project? then install babel/preset-react and add it to config. anything else?

Comment: @JoshuaSegal This page should have enough instructions to get you going: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react

Answer (score 0):

```
@babel/preset-react
```

should be installed. And while compiling jsx -> js code:

```
--presets @babel/react
```

arguments should be supplied. So your compile code will look to similar like this:

```
npx babel BlueSlide/js/student_slider.jsx --presets @babel/react --watch --out-file BlueSlide/static/js/student_slider_compiled.js
```